# NMAKE.EXE and files with multiple periods

Tags: visual-c++, protocol-buffers, nmake

I want to use nmake.exe under Windows to build a C++ project that makes use of Google protobufs.  This requires executing protoc.exe for all .proto files in the project.

The problem I'm having is coming up with a rule in nmake.exe that will compile a .proto file, caused by the fact that the output from protoc.exe is a file of the form .pb.cc

Neither of the following work:

```
.SUFFIXES: .proto .cc

.proto.cc:
        protoc.exe -cpp_out=<target folder> $<
```

or

```
.SUFFIXES: .proto .pb.cc

.proto.pb.cc:
        protoc.exe -cpp_out=<target folder> $<
```

The second produces the following error:

```
filename.mk(3) : fatal error U1092: too many names in rule
```

which is no great surprise, however the first fails silently.  I'm fairly certain the first case fails because the filename "stems", as gnu make calls them, don't match due to the addition of the ".pb" sequence in the name.